# How to get selected product attribute label and option label in magento 2.4.2-p1

Tags: configurable-product, shopping-cart, magento2.4.2-p1

**Here id configrable product:-**

[image]

**Simple product assign to configrable product:-**

[image]

**How to get a product that simple product attribute label and value using parent product id or child product id ???**

[image]

Comment: Can you please mention where you want to show the selected (one of the configurable product) simple product's attribute? as you know cart page, order page and etc are different areas. So more specific details in question will be helpful.

Comment: in custom phtml file. i have also configrable and simple product id